# Are h- and g-parameters only applicable to two-port networks?

Tags: rf, microwave, s-parameters

There are plenty of references to various ways to represent two-port networks (S, Z, Y, T, ABCD, h and g parameters).

S and T parameters are commonly generalised to N-port networks. Is the same true of h and g parameters?

If I look at the definition of h-parameters in Wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-port_network#Hybrid_parameters_(h-parameters)

It seems that, if I had e.g. a 3-port network, I could get \$h_{13} = \frac{V_1}{V_3}|_{I_3=0}\$. Is this valid?

Formulas are also available to convert from S-parameters to h-parameters in the 2-port case, but I'm not sure how to generalise them if this is at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

H-param just means a combination of measurement methods are used to extract the numbers. This is a separate issue from # ports.